# Generating diff view using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json containing revision/history info of modified entity which holds its old and new values. Diff is generated with https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch and I've done additional parsing myself to form final json format to be rendered.

Example data:

```
[
  {
    "createdBy": "admin@localhost",
    "modifiedAt": 1445113889873,
    "left": [
      {
        "Status": "Open"
      }
    ],
    "right": [
      {
        "Status": "In Progress"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "createdBy": "admin@localhost",
    "modifiedAt": 1445114315786,
    "left": [
      {
        "Description": "hello"
      },
      {
        "Assignee": "Uncle Bob (test@test)"
      }
    ],
    "right": [
      {
        "Description": "bye"
      },
      {
        "Assignee": "Willy Wonka (willy@hello)"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am looking a nice way to form a table for this where for each revision I get separately left and right columns and values on separate rows. Probably tired, but I can't figure out how would ng-repeat work for this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.revisions | orderBy:'-modifiedAt'">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="20%">Field</th>
          <th width="40%">Old Value</th>
          <th width="40%">New Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I am hoping for result like this:

[image: expected]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am right about data format:

```
<div ng-repeat="revision in vm.revisions | orderBy:'-modifiedAt'">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="20%">Field</th>
        <th width="40%">Old Value</th>
        <th width="40%">New Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="(index, left) in revision.left">
      <tr ng-repeat="(field, leftValue) in left">
        <td>{{field}}</td>
        <td>{{leftValue}}</td>
        <td>{{revision.right[index][field]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

See it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6zqgfr8/